# Why does this code to call a function for a period of time freeze?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
from time import time

def multiply(n1, n2):
    return n1 * n2

# Causes Python to freeze (CASE 1)
def not_working_1_timed_exec(func, sec, *args, **kwargs):
    start = time()
    while time() - start < sec:
        yield func(*args, **kwargs)

# print(list(not_working_1_timed_exec(multiply, 5, 2, 5)))

# Causes Python to freeze (CASE 2)
def not_working_2_timed_exec(func, sec, *args, **kwargs):
    start = time()
    ret = []
    while time() - start < sec:
        ret.append(func(*args, **kwargs))
    return ret

# print(list(not_working_2_timed_exec(multiply, 5, 2, 5)))

# Works
def timed_exec(func, sec, *args, **kwargs):
    start = time()
    while time() - start < sec:
        print('hello world') # MAKES IT WORK
        yield func(*args, **kwargs)

print(list(timed_exec(multiply, 5, 2, 5)))
```

The goal is to write a simple function that accepts a function as a parameter and calls it for a period of time

I would love to know why it does not work, and why `print()` makes the function work ?

Comment: What makes you think that it doesn't work without `print('hello world')`?

Comment: I can't reproduce this at all. Both of the supposedly "non-working" functions work fine for me. Of course they take 5 seconds to run before `list` gathers the output and `print` prints it, but they work fine.

Comment: Which Python version are you using? I use 3.9.6

Comment: @OmerMenahse 3.9.2.

Comment: It is not working in IDLE

Comment: Right, you left that crucial detail out, didn't you? On my machine, in PyCharm, function 1 manages to call the `multiply` function 28,741,713 times in 5 seconds. IDLE's output formatting probably chokes on the 118 megabyte string that is the stringified output of the list. (The function that spams "hello world" manages to call `multiply` 1,281,433 times, for an output of about 5.1 megabytes.)

Comment: Yep that is the answer, I've added a 0.5 sec delay and got a print, tyvm ! :)

Answer (score 2):

So, as discussed in the comments, this is not a bug in Python at all, it's a deficiency in IDLE's (which is what OP used) output printing, which chokes/seems to hang on a very long line (i.e. the result of the fast `not_working` version).

Making the function slower makes things seem to work, since there's no longer that much output to format.

Answer (score 0):

IDLE's output formatting probably chokes on the 118 megabyte string that is the stringified output of the list. (The function that spams "hello world" manages to call multiply 1,281,433 times, for an output of about 5.1 megabytes.)

Comment: @mkrieger1 I don't know, kind of smells like an answer to me, and Stack Overflow allows self answered questions.  I'm not sure it's a very good one though.

Comment: May I recommend giving credit where credit is due. Although perhaps not intentional, these are not your words, but copied from a comment.  Perhaps delete this (copied) comment and upvote and accept (click the tick mark) the answer by @AKX to say thank you.